Back to basics: Why do we care about symmetry of functions?
I am teaching a high school class on basic properties of functions, and like to motivate each of the properties with an example of why we even care to look at these properties. E.g. monotonicity allows economists to make predictions, continuity is used by engineers to describe waves and fluid dynamics, etc; you see: It's very high-level. But I am still having problems finding a reason why we would ever care about symmetry of functions, besides its obvious beauty (which most of my students don't appreciate).
Any hints to professions I might have overlooked or articles I could read are welcomed. :)
Thanks a lot in advance

Because Symmetry is largely used in nature.

Arguably, in high school, your students will not have signficant exposure to using math to solve scientific problems (e.g in finance, economics, engineering, physics, ...).  Then, focusing solely on math problems, the task of stretching your students intuition becomes iffy.  For example, the analytical solution of certain types of Inclusion-Exclusion problems becomes significantly easier when the symmetrical aspects of the problem are considered.  However, this approach may well be a non-starter for high school math students, because Inclusion-Exclusion may not even be taught until college

Knowing symmetries means less work to analyze the function , unless one has access to a computer anyway in which case it makes no difference. Sometimes , but rarely , symmetries also occur in real life problems or the nature.

Say you need to find the area of part of a parabola bounded by a horizontal line.  Rather than integrating from one intersection point (of the horizontal line and the parabola) to the other, you could integrate from one intersection point's x-value to the x-value of the line of symmetry and then double it.  Less work that way.

I think we can get some information from the symmetry of a function.
e.g. a simple sin function, it has period and we can use it to solve equations. and we can only draw a period instead of a whole graph.
e.g. standard normal distribution curve...
